# Is there a way to make changes to the `window.location` object directly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a submit handler where I'd like to navigate the user to `/path?query`, but I first found out that doing

```
window.location.pathname = `/path?query`
```

does not work as the `?` is encoded.
I then tried

```
const handleSubmit = ({ email }: Values) => {
  window.location = {
    ...window.location,
    pathname: "/path",
    search: `?email=${email}`,
  };
};
```

But I got `TypeError: Illegal invocation`.
Here is a code snippet.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const handleSubmitFactory = email => () => {
  window.location = {
    ...window.location,
    pathname: "path",
    search: `?email=${email}`,
  };
};

const handleChangeFactory = setEmail => ({ target: { value } }) => {
  setEmail(value);
};

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmitFactory(email)}>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" value={email} onChange={handleChangeFactory(setEmail)} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Is there a way to update the

Comment: Use a react routing/navigation library in your app? Don't mutate global objects. A common one is [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

Comment: Have you tried <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmitFactory(email)}> ?

Comment: @dOshu `handleChangeFactory` is a curried function that returns the function to consume the `onSubmit` event object when the submit event occurs.

Comment: @DrewReese I see, my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = `/path?query`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = `/path?query`
```

This worked for me